# How do I use Spock Spy?

Tags: spock, spy

I tried to use Spy test but it did not work. The following class is a Sut.

```
public class FileManager {
    public int removeFiles(String directory)    {
        int count = 0;
        if(isDirectory(directory))  {
            String[] files = findFiles(directory);
            for(String file : files)    {
                deleteFile(file);
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private boolean isDirectory(String directory) {
        return directory.endsWith("/");
    }

    private String[] findFiles(String directory) {
        // read files from disk.
        return null;
    }

    private void deleteFile(String file)    {
        // delete a file.
        return;
    }
}
```

Then, I created a test like the below.

```
class SpyTest extends Specification  {
def "Should return the number of files deleted"()   {
    given:
    def fileManager = Spy(FileManager)
    1 * fileManager.findFiles("directory/") >> { return ["file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"] }
    fileManager.deleteFile(_) >> { println "deleted file."}

    when:
    def count = fileManager.removeFiles("directory/")

    then:
    count == 4
}
```

But I got NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at example.spock.mock.FileManager.removeFiles(FileManager.java:8)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CglibRealMethodInvoker.respond(CglibRealMethodInvoker.java:32)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockInvocation.callRealMethod(MockInvocation.java:60)
at org.spockframework.mock.CallRealMethodResponse.respond(CallRealMethodResponse.java:29)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.handle(MockController.java:49)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockInterceptor.intercept(JavaMockInterceptor.java:72)
at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CglibMockInterceptorAdapter.intercept(CglibMockInterceptorAdapter.java:30)
at example.spock.mock.SpyTest.Should return the number of files deleted(SpyTest.groovy:13)
```

It means the real method is called. Is there any reason why it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

In Spock, you can't mock private methods of a java class. Looking at your `FileManager` it's not clear why only `removeFiles` is public but others are private. Although all methods are related to file management. Possible solutions would be:

1. Make the rest of the `FileManager` methods public. This way Spock will work and `FileManager` will actually become a file manager, not just file remover
2. Decompose `FileManager` into different components. So you can mock these components separately and inject them into "file remover". Basically you already decomposed your code at the methods level. But private java methods are [not mockable in Spock](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/403). And class decomposition might be overhead because `FileManager` looks kind of cohesive with all of its operations
3. Use other test/mocking frameworks that can mock private methods. E.g. mockito and powermock. However, mocking private methods is the worst option because it can harm maintainability of the entire codebase in the long term if out of control